# Adding state to <Link> overrides the other properties like 'search' & 'params'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `Link` with-state and without-state as:

```
<Link to={{pathname: "/test/profile?id=123", state: {key: "value"}}}>Resend</Link>    
<Link to="/test/profile?id=123"}>Resend</Link>
```

Adding the state to `Link` override the other props from the component.
Without state gives props as:

```
{
  "history": {
    "length": 10,
    "action": "PUSH",
    "location": {
      "pathname": "/test2/profile?id=123",
      "state": {
        "key": "value"
      },
      "search": "",
      "hash": "",
      "key": "3u9qkj"
    }
  },
  "location": {
    "pathname": "/test2/profile",
    "search": "?id=123",
    "hash": "",
    "key": "m5btna"
  },
  "match": {
    "path": "/test2/:type",
    "url": "/test2/profile",
    "isExact": true,
    "params": {
      "type": "profile"
    }
  }
}
```

And with state:

```
{
  "history": {
    "length": 10,
    "action": "PUSH",
    "location": {
      "pathname": "/test2/profile?id=123",
      "state": {
        "key": "value"
      },
      "search": "",
      "hash": "",
      "key": "3u9qkj"
    }
  },
  "location": {
    "pathname": "/test2/profile?id=123",
    "state": {
      "key": "value"
    },
    "search": "",
    "hash": "",
    "key": "3u9qkj"
  },
  "match": {
    "path": "/test2/:type",
    "url": "/test2/profile?id=123",
    "isExact": true,
    "params": {
      "type": "profile?id=123"
    }
  }
}
```

So, `history` is same but `location` and `match` are completely different.

What do I want?
I want `location.search` and `match.params` to be consistent with or without state. How do I handle it?

version: `react-router-dom: 5.1.2,`

Comment: Have you tried `<Link to={{pathname: "/test/profile?id=123"}}>Resend</Link> `

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/test/profile",
    search: "?id=123",
    state: { key: "value" }
  }}
>
  Resend State
</Link>
<Link to="/test/profile?id=123">Resend no state</Link>
```

Comment: That would add `search` but still `props.match` is different.

Comment: Can you please host your code i.e. codepen or somewhere else